# Aurelia-Polymer Using CLI tool

Tags: javascript, web, aurelia

I've been trying to sort this out for a while; my goal is to use Polymer modules inside the Aurelia framework. There's a tutorial [here](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/integrating-with-polymer/1) (on the official documentation), but that's not for a CLI generated app.

my **aurelia.json** file has the following dependencies:

```
…
"aurelia-html-import-template-loader",
"aurelia-polymer",
…
```

(installed using npm)

and the **index.html** file looks like this:

```
<head>
<title>Aurelia</title>

<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
```

…

I have no errors in the CLI/console upon building.

**main.js**

```
aurelia.use.plugin('aurelia-polymer');
```

loads fine but

```
aurelia.use.plugin('aurelia-html-import-template-loader');
```

gives errors in the browser console:

```
vendor-bundle.js:21513 GET http://localhost:9000/app.html 
Unhandled rejection Error: Load timeout for modules: template-registry- ………
```

I've been talking to a bunch of lads on aurelia/gitter, but so far I've found nobody who was able to get 'aurelia-html-import-template-loader'working in the CLI.

Thanks for reading,
have an awesome day

Answer (score 0):

From [aurelia-polymer](https://github.com/roguePanda/aurelia-polymer):

> Using with Webpack
>
> If you're using webpack, you won't be able to use
>   aurelia-html-import-template-loader, which means you won't be able to
>   load Polymer elements in your templates directly (see #18). Instead,
>   it's suggested that you use [vulcanize](https://github.com/Polymer/vulcanize) to bundle all the Polymer
>   elements you use into one file that can be loaded in index.html. The
>   elements will still be available in your templates once loaded, but
>   this avoids the syntax issues that require the HTML import template
>   loader.

I haven't tried it with aurelia-cli yet, but it's worth a shot.